# Implementing U-net for multi-class road segmentation

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am trying to train a U-net for image segmentation on satellite data and therewith extract a road network with nine different road types. Thus far I have tried many different U-net codes that are freely available on the web, however I was not able to tailor them to my specific case. I'm sincerely hoping you are able to help me.

The satellite image and associated labels can be downloaded via the following link:
[Satellite image and associated labels](https://www49.zippyshare.com/v/5pR3GPv3/file.html)

Additionally, I've written the following code to prep the data for the Unet

```
import skimage
from skimage.io import imread, imshow, imread_collection, concatenate_images
from skimage.transform import resize
from skimage.morphology import label
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, merge, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Reshape, core, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon
import shapely.wkt
import shapely.affinity
from collections import defaultdict

#Importing image and labels
labels = skimage.io.imread("ede_subset_293_wegen.tif")
images = skimage.io.imread("ede_subset_293_20180502_planetscope.tif")[...,:-1]

#Scaling image
img_scaled = images / images.max()

#Make non-roads 0
labels[labels == 15] = 0

#Resizing image and mask and labels
img_scaled_resized = img_scaled[:6400, :6400,:4 ]
print(img_scaled_resized.shape)
labels_resized = labels[:6400, :6400]
print(labels_resized.shape)

#splitting images
split_img = [
    np.split(array, 25, axis=0) 
    for array in np.split(img_scaled_resized, 25, axis=1)
]

split_img[-1][-1].shape

#splitting labels
split_labels = [
    np.split(array, 25, axis=0) 
    for array in np.split(labels_resized, 25, axis=1)
]

#Convert to np.array
split_labels = np.array(split_labels)
split_img = np.array(split_img)

train_images = np.reshape(split_img, (625, 256, 256, 4))
train_labels = np.reshape(split_labels, (625, 256, 256))

x_trn = train_images[:400,:,:,:]
x_val = train_images[400:500,:,:,:]
x_test = train_images[500:625,:,:,:]

y_trn = train_labels[:400,:,:]
y_val = train_labels[400:500,:,:]
y_test = train_labels[500:625,:,:]

plt.imshow(train_images[88,:,:,:])
skimage.io.imshow(train_labels[88,:,:])
```

Furthermore, I found the following U-net on kaggle, which I think should have to work for this particular case:

```
def get_unet():
    inputs = Input((8, ISZ, ISZ))
    conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)

    conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(pool4)
    conv5 = Convolution2D(512, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv5)

    up6 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv5), conv4], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Convolution2D(256, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv6)

    up7 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6), conv3], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv7)

    up8 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7), conv2], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv8)

    up9 = merge([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8), conv1], mode='concat', concat_axis=1)
    conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same')(conv9)

    conv10 = Convolution2D(N_Cls, 1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input=inputs, output=conv10)
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[jaccard_coef, jaccard_coef_int, 'accuracy'])
    return model
```

I know it is a big question, but I'm getting pretty desperate. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you add what the actual problem is? Is the code not compiling? Is your training/test accuracy bad?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Thomas. I just can't get the u-net to run on my dataset. It's all there, the train val and test set with associating labels but somehow I do not get the input right.

Comment: But what is the problem? Is it a compilation error? Is your accuracy wrong? Does it crash? You should at least post the code that is producing the error and the error itself.

Comment: Allright clear. There is no error but I just don't understand how to get the U-net to process the data in an iterable manner. Your absolutely right that the question is too broad and perhaps somewhat vague though. I will continue to work on the script and try to be more specific next time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**i found that Conv2DTranspose works better than UpSampling2D and here is a quick implementation using the same**

```
def conv_block(tensor, nfilters, size=3, padding='same', initializer="he_normal"):
    x = Conv2D(filters=nfilters, kernel_size=(size, size), padding=padding, kernel_initializer=initializer)(tensor)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters=nfilters, kernel_size=(size, size), padding=padding, kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)
    return x


def deconv_block(tensor, residual, nfilters, size=3, padding='same', strides=(2, 2)):
    y = Conv2DTranspose(nfilters, kernel_size=(size, size), strides=strides, padding=padding)(tensor)
    y = concatenate([y, residual], axis=3)
    y = conv_block(y, nfilters)
    return y


def Unet(img_height, img_width, nclasses=3, filters=64):
# down
    input_layer = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, 3), name='image_input')
    conv1 = conv_block(input_layer, nfilters=filters)
    conv1_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = conv_block(conv1_out, nfilters=filters*2)
    conv2_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = conv_block(conv2_out, nfilters=filters*4)
    conv3_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = conv_block(conv3_out, nfilters=filters*8)
    conv4_out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)
    conv4_out = Dropout(0.5)(conv4_out)
    conv5 = conv_block(conv4_out, nfilters=filters*16)
    conv5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)
# up
    deconv6 = deconv_block(conv5, residual=conv4, nfilters=filters*8)
    deconv6 = Dropout(0.5)(deconv6)
    deconv7 = deconv_block(deconv6, residual=conv3, nfilters=filters*4)
    deconv7 = Dropout(0.5)(deconv7) 
    deconv8 = deconv_block(deconv7, residual=conv2, nfilters=filters*2)
    deconv9 = deconv_block(deconv8, residual=conv1, nfilters=filters)
# output
    output_layer = Conv2D(filters=nclasses, kernel_size=(1, 1))(deconv9)
    output_layer = BatchNormalization()(output_layer)
    output_layer = Activation('softmax')(output_layer)

    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer, name='Unet')
    return model
```

**Now for the data generators, you can use the builtin ImageDataGenerator class
here is the code from Keras docs**

```
# we create two instances with the same arguments
data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=True,
                     featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                     rotation_range=90,
                     width_shift_range=0.1,
                     height_shift_range=0.1,
                     zoom_range=0.2)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

# Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
seed = 1
image_datagen.fit(images, augment=True, seed=seed)
mask_datagen.fit(masks, augment=True, seed=seed)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/images',
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/masks',
    class_mode=None,
    seed=seed)

# combine generators into one which yields image and masks
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000,
    epochs=50)
```

**Another way to go is implement your own generator by extending the Sequence class from Keras**

```
class seg_gen(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size, image_dir, mask_dir):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.samples = len(self.x)
        self.image_dir = image_dir
        self.mask_dir = mask_dir

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        idx = np.random.randint(0, self.samples, batch_size)
        batch_x, batch_y = [], []
        drawn = 0
        for i in idx:
            _image = image.img_to_array(image.load_img(f'{self.image_dir}/{self.x[i]}', target_size=(img_height, img_width)))/255.   
            mask = image.img_to_array(image.load_img(f'{self.mask_dir}/{self.y[i]}', grayscale=True, target_size=(img_height, img_width)))
#             mask = np.resize(mask,(img_height*img_width, classes))
            batch_y.append(mask)
            batch_x.append(_image)
        return np.array(batch_x), np.array(batch_y)
```

**Here is a sample code to train the model**

```
unet = Unet(256, 256, nclasses=66, filters=64)
print(unet.output_shape)
p_unet = multi_gpu_model(unet, 4)
p_unet.load_weights('models-dr/top_weights.h5')
p_unet.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='logs', write_graph=True)
mc = ModelCheckpoint(mode='max', filepath='models-dr/top_weights.h5', monitor='acc', save_best_only='True', save_weights_only='True', verbose=1)
es = EarlyStopping(mode='max', monitor='acc', patience=6, verbose=1)
callbacks = [tb, mc, es]
train_gen = seg_gen(image_list, mask_list, batch_size)


p_unet.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=steps, epochs=13, callbacks=callbacks, workers=8)
```

**I have tried using the dice loss when i had only two classes, here is the code for it**

```
def dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    return score

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = 1 - dice_coeff(y_true, y_pred)
    return loss
```

Comment: why does Conv2DTranspose work better than Upsampling2D? it works better in terms of computational load? precision? code elegance?. Thanks.

Comment: `Conv2DTranspose` is a learnable layer hence the during training, the upscaling can be *learnt* and hence gives a much better result, while `Upsampling2D` has no learnable parameters.

Comment: and there is no image_generator or mask_generator for validation? this example only consider **training** data, unless you assume to use the validation_split in data_gen_args. thank you @SrihariHumbarwadi

Comment: @SrihariHumbarwadi What if we have more than 3 number of classes?